# Binary image classifier always predicting one class

Tags: python, keras, cnn, image-classification

I am trying to design a model for binary image classification, this is my first classifier and I am following an online tutorial but the model always predicts class 0

My dataset contains 3620 and 3651 images of each class respectively, I don't suppose the problem is due to an imbalanced dataset as the model is predicting only the class with lower number of sample in the dataset.

My code

```py
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Activation, Dropout, Flatten, Dense
from keras import backend as K 

img_hieght, img_width = 150,150
train_data_dir = 'dataset/train'
#validation_data_dir = 'dataset/validation'

nb_train_samples = 3000
#nb_validation_samples = 500

epochs = 10
batch_size = 16

if K.image_data_format() == 'channels_first':
    input_shape = (3, img_width, img_hieght)
else:
    input_shape = (img_width, img_hieght, 3)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32,(3,3), input_shape = input_shape))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

model.add(Conv2D(32,(3,3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

model.add(Conv2D(64,(3,3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(64))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss = 'binary_crossentropy', optimizer = 'rmsprop', metrics = ['accuracy'])

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale = 1. /255,
    shear_range = 0.2,
    zoom_range = 0.2,
    horizontal_flip = True)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_data_dir,
    target_size = (img_width,img_hieght),
    batch_size = batch_size,
    class_mode = 'binary')

model.fit_generator(train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch = nb_train_samples//batch_size,
    epochs = epochs)

model.save('classifier.h5')
```

I have tried checking the model summary as well, but couldn't detect anything notable

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 148, 148, 32)      896       
_________________________________________________________________
activation_1 (Activation)    (None, 148, 148, 32)      0         
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling2 (None, 74, 74, 32)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)            (None, 72, 72, 32)        9248      
_________________________________________________________________
activation_2 (Activation)    (None, 72, 72, 32)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_2 (MaxPooling2 (None, 36, 36, 32)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_3 (Conv2D)            (None, 34, 34, 64)        18496     
_________________________________________________________________
activation_3 (Activation)    (None, 34, 34, 64)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_3 (MaxPooling2 (None, 17, 17, 64)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_1 (Flatten)          (None, 18496)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 64)                1183808   
_________________________________________________________________
activation_4 (Activation)    (None, 64)                0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)          (None, 64)                0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 1)                 65        
_________________________________________________________________
activation_5 (Activation)    (None, 1)                 0         
=================================================================
Total params: 1,212,513
Trainable params: 1,212,513
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
None
```

I have not used validation dataset, I am using only training data and testing the model manually using:

```py
from keras.preprocessing import image
import numpy
import tensorflow as tf

categories = ['messi','ronaldo']
test_image= image.load_img('test4.jpeg', target_size = (150, 150)) 
test_image = image.img_to_array(test_image)
test_image = numpy.expand_dims(test_image, axis = 0)
test_image = test_image.reshape(-1,150, 150,3)

model = tf.keras.models.load_model('classifier.h5')
result = model.predict([test_image])   

print(model.summary())
```

Please consider that I have only recently started working on ML, I am anticipating some serious silly fault in the code.

Comment: Try adding more `Conv2D` layers. Also, normalize the images before training so that we don't encounter large numbers for the loss.

Answer (score 1):

Try [predict_generator](https://keras.io/models/sequential/)

```
imgen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1/255.)
testGene = imgen.flow_from_directory(<path to testing images>,
                                        target_size=(150, 150,),
                                        shuffle=False,
                                        class_mode="input",
                                        batch_size=batch_size,
                                        save_to_dir=None
                                        )

model = load_model("classifier.h5")
pred = model.predict_generator(testGene, steps=testGene.n/batch_size)
```

Testing folder should something like this

```
<path to testing images>/testing_folder/..test_img_1.jpg
                                        ..test_img_2.jpg
                                        ..
                                        ..
```

**you should pass directory path up to `<path to testing images>`"**

Comment: I tried this method, but the variable 'pred' seems to be returning an empty list.

Comment: make sure inside the <path to testing images> there should be a folder,test images should be inside the folder..keras image processing library get the folder as class.

Comment: I had created a folder and added 4 sample images to it. updated the path in the code like you suggested, still no good. Also. I tried changing the 'save_to_dir' parameter in the generator to my test folder, but there's nothing saved. Maybe the generator is not created for some reason ?

Comment: when you run `imgen.flow_from_directory()` function,it should print out something like this `Found 4 images belonging to 1 classes.`. Run line by line and check for this message and let me know the result.

Comment: I got `Found 0 images belonging to 0 classes.`

Comment: which means generator doesn't found your test image folder.make sure your `path to testing images` is correct and it has the above mentioned structure.issue with your file path

Comment: I now tried using a variable 'directory' to define the path, I then input the variable like: `flow_from_directory(directory = path)`, finally to make sure, I tried writing a text file to the same variable `path`. as expected, the file is written, so I guess the directory may be working fine. Even the image format is consistent throughout the program

Do I need to define classes manually ? or is it picked by the order of training

Comment: keras will take number of folders as classes.Or you can define classes as well..when you run it still get the message as 0 images  0 classes?

Comment: sadly, its still the same damn message `Found 0 images belonging to 0 classes.`

Comment: what are the file formats of your images?

Comment: .jpeg, same like the training format

Comment: change `class_mode:None` and check it again

Comment: No luck still. there's this exact discussion on https://www.kaggle.com/c/landmark-recognition-challenge/discussion/57716 apparently, Keras `flow_from_directory()` requires two folders depth like `test/samples/4567543.jpeg`. Now I atleast can be sure that the problem is path itself but still it does't work for me

Comment: I managed to get the `Found 4 images belonging to 1 classes.` seems like the sample images should be contained within folder like `test/samples/image01.jpeg` but the path should be defined without mentioning the folder `samples` in following manner: `path = 'test'`. Thanks its been a very learning experience! But the original problem still seems to be unresolved

Comment: @asiffarhankhan that's exactly what i told you..i guess you didn't read it carefully.anyway looks the problem is with your cnn architecture..can you post the loss values

Comment: I guess I totally missed out on that one. Sorry. Should I copy paste the loss values from the last epoch from training results ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104124/discussion-between-rajith-thennakoon-and-asiffarhankhan).